# How to avoid duplicating code with multiple constructors?

Tags: c#

I need help with multiple class constructors. I do not want to repeat my code, but how?

```
    public EventModel(string name, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
        : base(name)
    {
        StartTime = startTime;
        EndTime = endTime;
    }

    public EventModel(Guid id, string name, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
        : base(id, name)
    {
        StartTime = startTime;
        EndTime = endTime;
    }
```

I am looking something like this:

```
    public EventModel(Guid id, string name, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
        : this(name, startTime, endTime), base(id, name)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Can you modify the base class?

Comment: thats not correct solutions. I have more I analyzed it in a comment below. I cann't send default value to base constroctor,

Comment: @ReedCopsey No I cann't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often in situations like this I will refactor the code to a common method, the drawback with this is you can not set `readonly` fields.

```
public EventModel(string name, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    : base(name)
{
    Initialize(startTime, endTime);
}

public EventModel(Guid id, string name, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    : base(id, name)
{
    Initialize(startTime, endTime);
}

private void Initialize(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    StartTime = startTime;
    EndTime = endTime;
}
```

Comment: probably the cleanest solution as yet there was.Thanks

Comment: It's not what I was looking for, but what I'm looking for C # can not

Comment: @Sahuagin yes, that is why I said *"the drawback with this is you can not set `readonly` fields."*

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the base class to accept a nullable `Guid`, you can make the `id` parameter optional:

```
public EventModel(
   string name,
   DateTime startTime,
   DateTime endTime,
   Guid? id = null)
    : base(name, id)
{
   StartTime = startTime;
   EndTime = endTime;
}
```

Then in your base class, treat a null `id` the same as the constructor that takes only a `name`. It's possible doing this would prevent you from avoiding repetition in your base class, but at the same time you might be able to reduce repetition in your base class.

Also, I strongly suggest that you call your `Guid` type parameter `guid`. There is almost no benefit from shortening to `id`, and it is much more likely to confuse and slow down those looking at the code later.

Comment: At first, Guid is value type so cann't be null, but sure I can use default(Guid). At second, thats not correct, becouse this allways call base constructor with two parametrs and there is different logic between one parametr constructor and two.

Comment: @ReedCopsey My apologies, I made the Guid parameter nullable now.

Comment: @Peter Is there any reason you can't modify the base class?

Answer (score 0):

Provide default values for the constructor.

```
    public EventModel(Guid id = default(Guid), string name = "Default", DateTime startTime = new DateTime(0), DateTime endTime = new DateTime(0))
    : base(id, name)
{
    StartTime = startTime;
    EndTime = endTime;
}
```

Comment: This will only work if the base class supports it - as written, you'd probably get different behavior than the original, since the base class may be doing something different if Guid isn't provided...

Comment: You can't assign `0` to `Guid`

Comment: What if start and end time were set in a seperate method that is called from the constructors?

Answer (score 0):

have the base class be implemented like this. Below is just an example

base class

```
public Text(): this(0, 0, null) {}
public Text(int x, int y): this(x, y, null) {}
public Text(int x, int y, string s) {
  // Actual constructor implementation
```

Sample use

```
Text t1 = new Text();               // Same as Text(0, 0, null)
Text t2 = new Text(5, 10);            // Same as Text(5, 10, null)
Text t3 = new Text(5, 20, "Hello");
```